# How to plot a histogram from existing counts with uneven bin widths using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to create an histogram from already existing classes. I have this dataset:

```
interval        counts
0 - 8.50        2577
8.51 - 10.00    1199
10.01 - 12.00   1878
12.01 - 14.00   637
14.01 - 16.00   369
16.01 - 18.00   98
18.00 - 20.00   308



library(ggplot2)

plot_tab5_lohn <- ggplot(DS18, aes(x=interval)) + geom_histogram(stat="count")
return(plot_tab5_lohn)})
```

does result in this graph:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3GDH.png]

I want the counts to be on the y axis and the intervals have to be a different width. How can I do this?

EDIT:
I've made it this far: 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3GDH.png]
using this code

```
DS18$interval <- factor(DS18$interval, levels = DS18$interval)
output$DS32 <- renderPlot({
plot_tab5_lohn <- ggplot(DS18, aes(x=interval, y = counts)) +
geom_col() + 
geom_point(color = "red") + 
geom_line(aes(group = 1), color = "red")
return(plot_tab5_lohn)
})
```

I'd like the bars to be as wide as the interval itself. And the density should be on the Y-Axis. The sum of the areas should be 1 (100%) then. 
Something like this [link](https://mathsstatistics.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/4/2/13423777/freqpoly.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the boundaries, then plot using `geom_rect`:

```
# Using dt from @www
library(tidyr)
dt2 <- separate(dt, interval, c('left', 'right'), sep = ' - ', convert = TRUE)
ggplot(dt2) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = left, xmax = right, ymin = 0, ymax = counts),
            col = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = right + (left - right) / 2, y = counts),
            col = 'red')
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can first expand your data into single observations, this also easily allows you to plot the densities instead:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dt3 <- dt %>% 
  group_by(interval) %>% 
  do(data.frame(interval = rep.int(.$interval, .$counts), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) %>% 
  separate(interval, c('left', 'right'), sep = ' - ', convert = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(value = right + (left - right) / 2)
breaks <- c(0, unique(dt3$right))

ggplot(dt3, aes(value)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), breaks = breaks, col = 1) +
  geom_freqpoly(aes(y = ..density..), breaks = breaks, col = 'red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is not a histogram, but a barplot. Here I showed how to use `geom_col` to create a barplot. Notice that I used `factor` to sort the bar of each class before plotting the data.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Order the bar
dt$interval <- factor(dt$interval, levels = dt$interval)
# Create the bar plot
ggplot(dt, aes(x=interval, y = counts)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "interval        counts
'0 - 8.50'        2577
                 '8.51 - 10.00'    1199
                 '10.01 - 12.00'   1878
                 '12.01 - 14.00'   637
                 '14.01 - 16.00'   369
                 '16.01 - 18.00'   98
                 '18.00 - 20.00'   308",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to have the histogram for visualizing the density of the intervals and after that I want overlay a frequency polygon over the histogram as well. Do you know if this is possible from my data?

Comment: @FragenSteller I am not sure how to overlay a frequency polygon. You may want to post a new question with a reproducible example and desired output addressing this.

Comment: @FragenSteller Try `ggplot(dt, aes(x=interval, y = counts)) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(group = 1), color = "red")`

Comment: Thanks again! I updated  my code and it looks a lot better now. But still not quite what I want it toby. I updated my original post. Can you please have a look at it? Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: I think Axeman provided a nice solution. Please consider accepting his answer without further modifying your original question.

Comment: Thank you again for your effords. I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stat = "identity"` and add a y aesthetic to get your desired graph:

```
ggplot(DS18, aes(x=interval, y = counts)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat="identity")
```

that gives you this:

[image]

Comment: `geom_col` is the modern shortcut for that. Any clues how to do the differently sized bins with a barplot?